Is it possible for Spectral (or another tool) to enforce query parameter / response object pairs within an OpenAPI / Swagger spec?
I have an OpenAPI 3.0 specification, and I am using Spectral to enforce some simple rules like naming conventions and the like.
However, there other more complex situations that I have been trying to figure out a pattern for without much luck.
For instance:
In the following example, notice that GET requires some pagination parameters. Also, the 200 response includes a PaginationStats object in addition to an array of ChildOrg objects.
paths:

/organizations/{organizationId}/childorgs:
    get:
      summary: Returns all child orgs for a given parent org.
      operationId: getChildOrgs
      parameters:
        - name: organizationId
          in: path
          description: The parent organization's ID
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/PaginationSorts'
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/PaginationPageSize'
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/PaginationOffset'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                properties:
                  childOrgs:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/ChildOrg'
                  paginationStats:
                    type: object
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/PaginationStats'


I want to enforce that if a pagination parameter is included as a query parameter, that a PaginationStats object must also be included as part of the 200 response.
Unfortunately the OpenAPI 3 spec does not accomodate enforcing a rule like this.
Things I've considered:

Simple rules seem unable to handle a complex case like this on their own. Or am I missing something?
A set of related simple rules could work together to accomplish the desired result, but I am having trouble identifying how that might be structured.
I've also considered changing conventions regarding how parameters or response objects are named and various ways of cross referencing them, but I haven't found a pattern that seems to work.

Of course, I could build some custom tool or custom spectral function from scratch to enforce this, but I'd prefer to use an existing toolset.
Is Spectral capable of handling this?
If so, what pattern might I consider?
Are there other yaml/json linting tools that might be more suited to this kind of application?

As far as I know there is no ready-made tool for this check at the moment. I usually use Python scripts to do similar custom checks.

Yeah, I suspected similar.
